# выйти из приложения находясь в Fragmentе

Tags: android, android-fragment

```
public class HorizontalPagerFragment_exit extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_horizontal2,container,false);
        Button but1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        Button but2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.no);
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: как выйти из приложения находясь в Fragmentе

Comment: взять активити и сделать ей `finish()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

или

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("CLOSE APP", true);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
getActivity().finish();
```

B MainActivity onCreate() надо добавить

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("CLOSE APP", false)){
    finish();
}
```

Comment: System.exit(0) - крайне неудачное решение, которое не стоит использовать

Answer (score 2):

Это изи

```
getActivity().finish();
```